# Saltstack - Error - No Top file or external nodes data matches found

Tags: linux, configuration-management, saltstack

I'm trying to configure my Saltstack Architecture.
I followed all the steps, but It seems not working and I'm not able to find the problem.

**/etc/salt/master**

```
file_roots:
base:
 - /srv/salt
dev:
 - /srv/salt/dev/states
prod:
 - /srv/salt/prod/states
adm:
 - /srv/salt/adm/states
```

**/srv/salt/top.sls**

```
base:
  '*':
    - admins
```

**admins.sls** is a state file in the /srv/salt directory.

What's wrong with this configuration? I'm not able to understand. Thank you very much for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was because of the difference of version between master and minion. After having updated the two systems, everything has worked.